# Failed to initialize output adapters while starting LiveDemo project's instance in FiWARE CEP

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

Error occurred while starting while starting LiveDemo project's instance in FiWARE CEP. it fails to initialize the output adapters.

```
INFO [Thread-27] com.ibm.hrl.proton.server.adapter.OutputServer.run Proton output server started, listening on output port: 3302
WARNING [pool-11-thread-1] com.ibm.hrl.proton.server.adapter.AbstractServer.startAdapters initializeAdapters: failed to initialize adapter Output adapter for consumer: SimpleFile, reason: No such file or directory
WARNING [pool-11-thread-1] com.ibm.hrl.proton.server.adapter.AbstractServer.startAdapters initializeAdapters: failed to initialize adapter Output adapter for consumer: File, reason: No such file or directory
INFO [Thread-26] com.ibm.hrl.proton.server.adapter.InputServer.run Proton server Started, listening on port: 3002
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct the path mentioned under "filename" field in the consumer.
Please follow below steps to remove the above mentioned error:
On Fiware PROTON GUI:

```
1. click on the Consumers in the resource navigation area.
2. double click on "File" consumer
3. update value of "filename" field in the Editing area(in the center).
   note: make sure the path is absolute not relative as tomcat's directory location can different in various linux falvours.
and make sure the all the directories mentioned in the path exists(file will be created automatically while initializing the adapter).
4. do the same for "SimpleFile" consumer.
5. click on "Save and Export" button at the top.
6. click on "Export to external repository" in the pop-up window.
7. Input destination and click ok.
```

After above steps stop the instance and start it again via REST API calls.

stop the instance:

> PUT
>   //localhost:8080/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/instances/ProtonOnWebServer
>   {"action":"ChangeState","state":"stop"}

start the instance:

> PUT
>   //localhost:8080/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/instances/ProtonOnWebServer
>   {"action":"ChangeState","state":"start"}